# Reincarnation manhua about a female lead who is entangled with an emperor and sent to her family estate to recover from "hysteria"

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I have been searching for a reincarnation manhua that features a female main lead. I read this manhua a while ago, so the details are rather hazy, but here is what I remember.

- When she reincarnated, it was revealed she had jumped into a lake at the behest of her love, the emperor.
- The emperor is entangled with her, although she realizes that he is toxic and mistreated her.
- Her father loves her and tries to placate her with money and other things.
- She is betrothed to a fiancé that doesn't really like her.
- At some point. she gets sent to her family estate to recover from "hysteria."
- I can't quite remember the female lead's hair colour, though I want to say it was blonde.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the female lead's hair? Also, when you said _"at the behest of her life, the emperor"_, did you mean the behest of her _love_...?

Comment: Yes, im sorry! She loved the emperor in her past life I think, and if I remember correctly he told her to jump into the lake. I can’t quite remember her hair colour, though I want to say it was blonde.

Comment: So is this one of those manhua where the protagonist dies and then wakes up as their younger self? And is the female lead betrothed to the emperor or someone else?

Comment: It’s along the same lines of those! If I remember correctly the lead woke up after she jumped in the lake, presumably committing  suicide. After she wakes up she resolves to turn her life around. She’s betrothed to another noble man but he’s not the emperor. I believe he has black hair?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying those points. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: @redsenma Was this definitely a (Chinese) manhua? Was it a reincarnated as the opposite gender story? It sounds a bit like a manhwa I read a while back. I don't remember the hysterics bit happening specifically, but it wouldn't be surprising given that she suddenly lost interest in someone she was fiercely courting, acts nothing like she used to, and is obsessed with trying to kill the guy who killed her (as a male) in her past life.

Comment: I don’t think she was a male in her past life. I’m pretty sure it’s a Korean manga/webcomic.

Comment: Do you recall if her past life was in our world or in the same world? Any idea what year you read this? About where in the story is she sent off to the estate for hysterics; is this something that would happen in chapter 1, or ch 10, or ch 100? Do you recall what the emperor or her fiance look like, e.g. their hair color or any other distinguishing features?

Comment: It was a fictional world, but with titles still that were or still are used today on our world. I think her fiancé was a Duke, but I’m not entirely sure. I am leaning on the fact that he had black hair, however. I want to say it’s like between chapter 10-30. It wasn’t immediately in the story, but it wasn’t way later on either. Her fiancé also didn’t seem to approve of her/found her troublesome. Until she changed  her behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is *[From a Knight to a Lady](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/from-a-knight-to-a-lady)*, aka *How the Knight Lives as a Lady*. It is available on [webtoons](https://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/from-a-knight-to-a-lady/list?title_no=3164).

> Estelle meets her untimely death as a valiant knight of the Kingdom of Ersha. But death is not the end for Estelle -- three years after her demise, she finds herself reincarnated in the body of Lucifela Aydin, the spoiled and cold-hearted daughter of a count in the Empire of Jansgar. To her dismay, she finds that her country fell to Jansgar years ago, and that she is now betrothed to Zedekiah Heint, the son of a duke and her adversary in her previous life. Can Estelle discover the truth behind her death while attempting to navigate her new life as Lucifela?

The main character is a strong female knight and is betrayed and killed. She reincarnates as a weak noble lady with an awful personality that has a one-sided crush on the crown prince. Immediately prior to Estelle waking up in her body, Lucifela jumped in the lake and nearly (or actually) died.

A Duke is coerced into becoming her fiance, and he resents her for this, fully aware of her personality.

[image: Awful personality, lake]

After reincarnating, her personality changes drastically, she apparently loses interest in the crown prince, almost leaps off a balcony, and walks out into the rain carrying a sword despite her frail body. As a result, she is sent off to a countryside estate. The term "hysteria" is not used that I saw, but her behavior is very clearly a major motivation.

[image: Insulting the daughter to make the father uncomfortable]